# Is it possible to make xelatex to compile just once?

Tags: xetex, kile

I want and need to run all the incantation steps like bibtex and extra compilations only at the end of the day.
It can be useful to say that I am using TexLive for Kile/Debian, just in case there is only a specific solution.

Comment: If you want information about the last section to appear in a table of contents at the start then it necessarily requires multiple passes over the document.

Comment: It isn't clear at all xelatex only compiles twice if you run it twice, if you only do it once (which should be the normal case while working on a document) it will only compile your document once. What is the question?

Comment: Ok, I realised the problem is with Kile, I will post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kile enables by default the option "Automatically run additional tools." at Settings -> build tools -> xelatex.